# Are PWA App Data and Cookies Cleared When iPad Turned Off for Long Periods?

Tags: ios, ipad, progressive-web-apps, ipados

Getting reports from a client that they are being asked to re-login to their PWA (saved to their home screen) whenever they turn off their iPads for periods of 1-2hrs and then turn it back on again. Just noting, this isn't related to the 7 day cap on cookie data in webkit as we've already addressed this. The app, when the device is left on, doesn't ask the user to login until the cookie has expired. I think the client hasn't been turning off devices like this before. The app is designed to function offline.

I've tested just turning it off for a few minutes on a standard iPhone with iOS17 but don't experience the same issue.

The client has MDM installed so I'm attempting to test a device without this.

Does anyone know if it is part of iOS/iPadOS's device restart process to clear PWA data / cookies etc. if the device has been off for a long time?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, each app, including PWAs, has its dedicated storage space, and when it reaches capacity, iOS typically clears it. This limitation also applies to IndexedDB. However, I haven't personally encountered issues with data stored in IndexedDB being automatically deleted on iOS, and I suspect that this problem may have been resolved. In summary, iOS provides a generous storage capacity, and there doesn't seem to be a widespread issue with automatic deletion of data stored in IndexedDB.